# Offering bounty to another's question. What are the benefits?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty

If I had offered bounty on another's question then, what will be the benefits?

> Will I get reputations if the post is liked by community?

Comment: See also: [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The benefit is that you draw attention to the question, which raises the chances of getting a (good) answer, and everybody gets to hopefully learn something about chemistry.

> Will I get reputations if the post is liked by community?

No.